# Image being quantized, but I have no idea why

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I have two GUIs employing the same DLL (which I wrote) to process the same image. I have a strange issue where the image seems to be quantized by one of the GUIs despite the GUI not handling the image at all (the DLL does all the processing). I know this because I set a breakpoint immediately after the image is loaded within the DLL and then I write it to disk. When I create a histogram of the image I get different results for each GUI. Here's the first histogram (which is identical to the original image's histogram): [image]

And here's the second:
[image]

My best guess is that it's a 32/64 bit issue. I'm running both GUIs on my 64 bit machine using OpenCV version 2.2 32 bit DLLs. The first GUI has platform x86 and the second has platform Active (x86). Any ideas on how to fix this?